# Are Proxy settings on a MAC profile specific

Tags: networking, proxy, mac

Quite a specific question. I have an luser who is getting a mis-configured proxy error which is served by the proxy server if the user dosn't have the proxy settings. Before I drive over there was wondering if anyone knows if mac proxy settings are specific to an individual user or global. E.g. if she's logged in as a different user to the one I setup last week will she have lost these settings?

I believe it's the most recent or 1 version back of OS X.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why do so many people write Mac as MAC?

Comment: probably because we're all used to writing mac as in MAC address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Global. Stored in /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist

Comment: Thanks, they had managed to blank all settings as it happens.

A note for future googler's different settings are stored per adapter but not per user.